# Angular 17 application builder and serve

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I upgraded to angular 17 and now serve does not actually generate any files.  I am using the application builder to build now.  Has anybody else come across this issue?  I read the docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/esbuild) but it was pretty unclear.  There are no errors thrown but if I go inspect dev tools there are no files and the app just never loads.  I am including an image of what the build results look like.  I do get a ton of the warnings you see there but the only thing mentioned in files is main.ts anyway.  so no idea if that is related.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did some debugging of the serve command and noticed that it is checking specifically to see if the target is either of the below.  I was using a custom builder so the strings did not match and it was not building the correct thing.

```
if (builderName === '@angular-devkit/build-angular:application' ||
        builderName === '@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser-esbuild' ||
```